# Why is Mr. Steven in California and not Florida

Tags: spacex, reuse, fairings

Mr. Steven is the ship that is used to catch fairings. There is one of these thus far, and it is based to assist Vandenberg, not Cape Canaveral. Why are they choosing to test the fairing catching in the Pacific as opposed to the Atlantic?

Answer (score 4):

Best theory I have heard is that basing it in California leaves it closer to the mother ship in Hawthorne, CA where the engineers are.  (Where the Wild Things are?).

The team in Florida is launch focused.  The larger pool of engineering talent is still based at the home office.